# Wireless connection lost to a single system; requires rebooting router

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, internet-connection

I live with three friends, and we often sit in the living room with our laptops. There’s a WiFi router in the kitchen, and we have quite a stable connection.

The issue however, is that sometimes, all of a sudden one of my friends will lose their Internet connection. Even disconnecting and reconnecting to the WiFi network does not help. When we restart the router, it works like a charm for everybody.

The odd thing is, it happens just for this one Windows 7 laptop. We’ve switched routers (for a different reason) in the mean time, but the issue remained. This makes me suspect the laptop even more.

I realize that I’ve given few details, but I don’t really know what to do or try. Any suggestions what it might be or how to fix it?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "loses connection?"  Does it stay connected to the router?  Can it ping the router?  Lose connection completely?  Just lose DNS? etc?

Comment: He complains about losing internet connection, but I'll check this afternoon if he can actually ping the router when it drops. I believe he once said he couldn't restart the router via the web UI, so that would mean he'd lose connection to the router. I'll verify and elaborate. Thanks!

Comment: What model and hardware version are the routers?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest hard coding IP addresses first.
If this doesn't help the issue, try changing the channel your WiFi is on.

Comment: If the router were having trouble assigning IP addresses, they wouldn't have gotten a connection in the first place. If it were a channel problem *all* the connections would go down.

Comment: Exactly. He's getting an assignment, since there's a stable connection at first.